# Make own settings for Mac

Tags: settings

Please forgive for my english.
I want to make some own settings, exactly when I connect Ethernet cable to my Mac I would like to turn on internet sharing automatically. And also to do not turn off internet sharing when Mac asleep. Is there any way how to program it? By some another app, terminal or program own program, anyhow?
I tried app Control Plane but it not works always correctly.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Automator to write scripts, or doing some research on AppleScript to see if you could write something perpetually running in the background. It will take some work, but I'm fairly confident it's possible.

You can find Automator in your Applications folder.

Best of luck